# How to use MySQL in a C# / XAML project

Tags: mysql, xaml

I've been searching around the web trying to find out how to use MySQL in a XAML project. 
I've seen a bunch of examples where functions like MySqlConnection(...) are used and so forth, but none of them mentions if a specific assembly is necessary or if it's something you need to download first - like a dll. 
Something like that is needed since it doesn't work straight away.

Anyone knows that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download and install MySql .Net Connector. Tool provided by MySql to connect with .net. This will have the assemblies used to connect .Net Applications to MySql.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm guessing you mean http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ yes? :)

Comment: Yes, That is what I meant.